# Correct phrase: "registered under the scheme" or "registered in the scheme"

Tags: phrase-choice

I want to write that "children can be registered **(in/under)** the scheme, provided certain eligibility criteria are satisfied". Which would be the correct preposition to use?

Comment: under the scheme.

Comment: Can you please explain why "in" is incorrect?

Comment: Because the child is not "in" a scheme. If you are part of a scheme, or in it, that's another meaning of scheme. Scheme as in  something illegal. Here, scheme is like a plan. You are registered for it or under it (like a title).

Comment: This usage of "scheme" sounds like British English.  Should the question be tagged "british-english"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want to use

> Children can be registered **for** the scheme,

for example

> [If you are a parent and would like to register your child **for** school milk](http://www.coolmilk.com/schools/)

Comment: Yes, but once the child is registered, for doesn't work.

Comment: I think 'for' can work if already registered: "we registered for school milk last year" sounds OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

Because **for**, **under** and **in** all sound natural to me (**under** seems to be popular with official bodies) I did a bit of research in Google Ngrams:

- [registered for,registered in,registered under](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=registered%20for%2Cregistered%20in%2Cregistered%20under&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cregistered%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregistered%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregistered%20under%3B%2Cc0) - **in** much more
  common
- [register for,register in,register under](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=register+for%2Cregister+in%2Cregister+under&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cregister%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregister%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregister%20under%3B%2Cc0) - **for** and **in** more common
- [in the scheme,for the scheme,under the scheme](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+scheme%2C+for+the+scheme%2C+under+the+scheme&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20scheme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20scheme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunder%20the%20scheme%3B%2Cc0) - **in** more common
- [register in the scheme,register for the scheme,register under the scheme](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=register+in+the+scheme%2Cregister+for+the+scheme%2Cregister+under+the+scheme&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cregister%20for%20the%20scheme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregister%20under%20the%20scheme%3B%2Cc0) - **for** and **under** roughly equal (**for** slightly ahead); **in** not found
- [registered in the scheme,registered for the scheme,registered under the scheme](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=registered+in+the+scheme%2Cregistered+for+the+scheme%2Cregistered+under+the+scheme&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cregistered%20in%20the%20scheme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregistered%20for%20the%20scheme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregistered%20under%20the%20scheme%3B%2Cc0) - **under** most common

Conclusions? **Under** seems to be used in the phrase as asked; **for** is also possible.

But if I restrict the search to either British English or American English *for the full phrase* then **under** is the only result found. (Which is a bit odd, and may imply that **for** is only used in other dialects of English.) It doesn't make much difference for the other, shorter, phrases.